# Null pointer exception check

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a class file which when i compile shows me Null pointer exception in a particular line all the time. I handled null check as below.

```
108    doc = Jsoup.parse(html, brandUrl);

109    Element div = doc.getElementById("eventTTL");
110    String attr = div.attr("eventTTL");
111    Date closingDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(attr));
112    Elements mainForm = doc.select("div#main-form");
113    Elements mainDivs = mainForm.select("DIV");
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.textT.at.Chickyur.main(Chickyur.java:110)

```
if(div != null)
String attr = div.attr("eventTTL"); 

 Also tried 
 if(div.attr("eventTTL") != null)
 String attr = div.attr("eventTTL");
```

Still i keep getting the exceptions. What is wrong? any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you getting the NullPointerException? Post stack trace and relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell by the code posted above exactly how your code is structured, but this should fix the `NullPointerException`:

```
Element div = doc.getElementById("eventTTL");
String attr = "";

if(div != null)
    attr = div.attr("eventTTL");
```

If you continue getting Exceptions after that, I would guess the issue is elsewhere in the code and you need to update your example.

Answer (score 1):

The code change you made will result in a compile error. No class file will be created, so you are probably running the old broken class file.

You probably want do do this (extend the scope of the if).

```
doc = Jsoup.parse(html, brandUrl);

Element div = doc.getElementById("eventTTL");
if(div != null) {
    String attr = div.attr("eventTTL");
    Date closingDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(attr));
    Elements mainForm = doc.select("div#main-form");
    Elements mainDivs = mainForm.select("DIV");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your stack trace, I'm only guessing, but:

From the line you say is the error, it means that `div` is null, which would indicate that the previous line is the culprit, which would mean that your `doc` has no Element with an Id of `eventTTL`.

Try ensuring that your `doc` is valid, and the it actually has a `eventTTL`.